How to put all Btrfs snapshots by apt-btrfs-snapshot and timeshift into a specific directory?
I created a subvolume called @snapshots that's mounted inside /.snapshots
I noticed that apt-btrfs-snapshot stores the snapshot in the root/base of the partition, and Timeshift stores it in timeshift-btrfs subvolume at root.
I just want to centralize it, and I'm wondering if it's possible, similar to this guide I found?
